# Android - Reducing the number of activities used

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying a method to reduce the number of total activities used in an application by switching layouts using the same activity. What I am doing is -

```
/* Class A is the actual activity */
public class A extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        /*When the button is pressed, create an object of class B to switch layout*/
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            B b=new B(A.this);
        }
        });
    }
}


/*Classs B handles some operation*/
public class B{

    Activity a;

    /*Set the new layout inside the constructor or call some other function to do that*/
    B(Activity act){
        a=act;
        a.setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
    }
```

So, the Class B would switch the layout, do some operation.
I would like to know whether this method is good practice, and also if there are other methods to do the same. Thanks

Comment: I feel this will be maintenance night mare. Even though you have 100s of activities unless you start, they won't be active. With proper lifecycle calls you can keep minimal set of activies running.

Comment: @thinksteep So, it is better to use more activities than using it like this?

Comment: Yes, that is my opinion. Advantages I see are cleaner & dedicated activities.

Comment: I also agree, my first app had 8 activities. I managed to scale it down to 4 through better programming practices. Dedicated source files are easy to maintain, as thinksteep suggested. And your idea is interesting, but can be overcome in many ways by setting the properties of your activities in the manifest. Perhaps making it so only 1 instance of an activity can exist would suit your needs?

Comment: This is what Fragments are for. Use the compatibility library.

Comment: @RyanGray Actually, I was just looking for interesting ways to reduce the number of activities, and ended up doing this. But I felt that this might not be the best of practices

Comment: @TomDignan I think fragments are not available for Froyo, which I want to keep as the minimum requirement

Comment: @thinksteep So, is there any advantage to this method? Like reduced memory usage or something?

Comment: No, only advantage I see with your methodology is reduced file size. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly i don't think is a good practice because in this way to keep alive several classes in your stack because they are referenced by the main activiy class that is always running so it could be a waste of resources.

Managing several activities that handle specific task is much better in my opinion for 2 reason:

1. It adheres to the object oriented principles
2. You delegate to the OS the task to manage resources. For this reason activity class has a lifecycle in order to optimise the resources.